# Problem working with FMapWeakList and Parametrized Records

Tags: coq, beginner, coq-mathcomp

Consider the following definition of a record `R`, parametrized over an arbitrary `eqType`:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrnat eqtype.
From Coq Require Import DecidableType DecidableTypeEx FMapWeakList.


Record R {s : eqType}  := mkR {
    a : nat;
    b : s
}.
```

Now, I want to use `R` as a `UsualDecidableType` to index weak maps. Following examples [here](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.18.0/stdlib/Coq.Structures.DecidableTypeEx.html), a create a module `R_as_DT`:

```
Module R_as_DT <: UsualDecidableType.

    Parameter s : eqType.

    Definition t := @R s.
    Definition eq := @Logic.eq t.
    Definition eq_refl := @Logic.eq_refl t.
    Definition eq_sym := @Logic.eq_sym t.
    Definition eq_trans := @Logic.eq_trans t.

    Definition eq_dec : forall (x y : t), {eq x y} + {~ eq x y}.
        intros x y.
        destruct (x.(a) == y.(a)) eqn:Ha.
        2 : { 
            right; unfold eq; destruct x,y; cbv; intro H; inversion H.
            simpl in Ha; rewrite H1 in Ha; contradict Ha.
            apply Bool.not_false_iff_true; apply /eqP; reflexivity.
        }
        destruct (x.(b) == y.(b)) eqn:Hb.
        2 : { 
            right; unfold eq; destruct x,y; cbv; intro H; inversion H.
            simpl in Hb; rewrite H2 in Hb; contradict Hb.
            apply Bool.not_false_iff_true; apply /eqP; reflexivity.
        }
        destruct x,y; left; simpl in Ha,Hb; 
        move: Ha => /eqP Ha; move: Hb => /eqP Hb; subst.
        reflexivity.
    Defined.
    
End R_as_DT.
```

Then, I import the FMapWeakList module passing `R_as_DT` as parameter.

```
Module Import RMap := FMapWeakList.Make(R_as_DT).
```

Problem is that now, Coq does not understand that `R` is the same as `key`.

```
Definition R1 : R := mkR nat_eqType 0 0.

Fail Definition test := RMap.add R1 2.
```

Do I need to somehow specify explicitely that parameter `s` of module  `R_as_DT` is instantiated with `nat_eqType` ? The problem does not happen if `R` does not contain a type parameter.